# Split widget into smaller widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-provider

I have a big widget with 3 distinct parts (see comments in code).

**Question:**
how do I break the widget in 3 parts with the less rebuild when the state change?

From [provider documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), I guess I should use Consumer/Selector but the examples are a bit too succinct for me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/cultivator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/incarnation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CultivatorComponent  extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cultivator = Provider.of<Cultivator>(context);
    return Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              // Part 1: only need Cultivator.Name
              Text('Cultivator ${cultivator.name} is here'),

              // Part 2: only need Cultivator.Incarnations
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: cultivator.incarnations.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber[500],
                    child: Center(child: Text('Incarnation ${cultivator.incarnations[index].name} is here')),
                  );
                },),

              // Part 3: only need number of Cultivator.Incarnations
              if(cultivator.canCreateIncarnation())
                RaisedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      var newIncarnation = Incarnation();
                      cultivator.addIncarnation(newIncarnation);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    label: Text('add incarnation'))
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: It's a bit broad. What do you expect from an answer?

Comment: just advice or example how to split the widget in 3 parts, and what feature to use in provider. (Also very nice to see that the main dev of provider is answering.)

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really about "advice", it's about questions that have a single answer. :) I have trouble understanding what's your goal

Comment: Then how do I break the widget in 3 parts with the less rebuild when the state change? (I'll edit the question to add this)